# connect mysql database with python

Tags: python, mysql, django

i am very new to python Django. i need to connect the MySQL database with python, i really don't have any idea about that ..
i am using python 1.7.

tell me how to connect MySQL database with python. what settings i need to fill in settings.py.

i have goggled it but i am not getting a proper answer please tell me from the beaning how to achieve it.

i have run this command now what are the next steps ?

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

i really don't have any idea about the further steps, please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Well you just installed MySQL Database interface for python

> Make sure to run `pip freeze` and see `MySQL-python==1.2.5` is there or not .)

And include below snippet in  your *`settings.py`*

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'yourdatabasename',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```